# Process finished with exit code -1073741571 (0xC00000FD) Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm, anaconda

I know this question gets asked a lot but in my case it's a bit wierd. I just got a RTX 3080 and tried to install Tensorflow based on a tutorial I found on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/tensorflow/comments/jsalkw/rtx_3090_and_tensorflow_for_windows_10_step_by/). I did everything as described there:
Install Anaconda --> Python 3.8 --> TF-nightly v. 2.5.0 --> Visual Studio C++ --> Cuda 11.1.0 --> cuDNN 8.0.4 --> add path --> restart pc. Everything seems to work at first. I tried following command:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.config.list_physical_devices()
```

This works without any errors as you can see in the output:

```
C:\Users\loose\.conda\envs\tf2\python.exe C:/Users/loose/PycharmProjects/GenerateAutomatedEMail/python/test.py
2021-01-16 00:40:45.043205: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
2021-01-16 00:40:46.676446: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2021-01-16 00:40:46.699117: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1760] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:2d:00.0 name: GeForce RTX 3080 computeCapability: 8.6
coreClock: 1.785GHz coreCount: 68 deviceMemorySize: 10.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 707.88GiB/s
2021-01-16 00:40:46.699285: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
2021-01-16 00:40:46.713523: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_11.dll
2021-01-16 00:40:46.713626: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublasLt64_11.dll
2021-01-16 00:40:46.717017: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2021-01-16 00:40:46.718013: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2021-01-16 00:40:46.725508: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2021-01-16 00:40:46.728010: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_11.dll
2021-01-16 00:40:46.728534: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_8.dll
2021-01-16 00:40:46.728660: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1898] Adding visible gpu devices: 0

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I currently try to train the Seq2Seq model from the [TF tutorials](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/nmt_with_attention). The code is pretty much exactly the same but I use PyCharm instead of Jupyter and I put everything in a class but the code itself is identical. My complete code is availabe in [GitHub](https://github.com/Daniel-Fauland/GenerateAutomatedEMail/tree/test). When I want to train the model I get the error *"Process finished with exit code -1073741571 (0xC00000FD)"*. But there is no real error shown the program just finishes with this exit code:

```
C:\Users\loose\.conda\envs\tf2\python.exe C:/Users/loose/PycharmProjects/GenerateAutomatedEMail/python/train_model.py
2021-01-16 00:50:34.337791: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
2021-01-16 00:50:36.873698: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2021-01-16 00:50:36.894834: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1760] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:2d:00.0 name: GeForce RTX 3080 computeCapability: 8.6
coreClock: 1.785GHz coreCount: 68 deviceMemorySize: 10.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 707.88GiB/s
2021-01-16 00:50:36.895004: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
2021-01-16 00:50:36.909453: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_11.dll
2021-01-16 00:50:36.909542: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublasLt64_11.dll
2021-01-16 00:50:36.912954: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2021-01-16 00:50:36.914024: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2021-01-16 00:50:36.921476: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2021-01-16 00:50:36.924059: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_11.dll
2021-01-16 00:50:36.924660: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_8.dll
2021-01-16 00:50:36.924807: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1898] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021-01-16 00:50:36.925280: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2021-01-16 00:50:36.926213: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1760] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:2d:00.0 name: GeForce RTX 3080 computeCapability: 8.6
coreClock: 1.785GHz coreCount: 68 deviceMemorySize: 10.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 707.88GiB/s
2021-01-16 00:50:36.926418: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1898] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021-01-16 00:50:37.388811: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1300] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2021-01-16 00:50:37.388901: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1306]      0 
2021-01-16 00:50:37.388947: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1319] 0:   N 
2021-01-16 00:50:37.389134: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1446] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 7447 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce RTX 3080, pci bus id: 0000:2d:00.0, compute capability: 8.6)
2021-01-16 00:50:38.006971: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_8.dll
2021-01-16 00:50:38.586194: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:334] Loaded cuDNN version 8004
2021-01-16 00:50:38.709516: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_11.dll
2021-01-16 00:50:39.312210: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublasLt64_11.dll
2021-01-16 00:50:39.313013: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_bl

as.cc:1838] TensorFloat-32 will be used for the matrix multiplication. This will only be logged once.

Process finished with exit code -1073741571 (0xC00000FD)
```

So I tried to locate the line when the program crashes. I found out the it crashes as soon as I initialize the "BahdanauAttention" class as shown in this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfr9e.png).

**After testing for several hours I can assume/confirm a few things:**

- I can run normal (non tensorflow) code just fine without this error in this venv
- I do not run out of ram (only 17GB of 32GB ram in use at most)
- I don't have any programs open that may cause conflicts (like NVIDIA Broadcast or Jupyter Lab, etc.)

**Things I tested to fix the issue:**

- Reinstall Conda
- Create new venv
- Reinstall TF as well as all NVIVIDA drivers
- Try a different Python version (3.7 instead of 3.8)
- Restarte my pc

I'm sorta out of options at this point. Does anyone have an idea how this problem could be fixed?

Comment: Can you try with different Tensorflow stable version currently 2.4.

Comment: No unfortunately this is not possible due to the RTX 30 series not working with any stable version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upgrade the `Tensorflow` to latest stable version since `Tensorflow 2.4` version supports new `Nvidia's` `Ampere` architecture which is of `RTX 30` series  and `CUDA 11` support also is available.
You can check in this chart for details and follow the guide to install the same.
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#tested_build_configurations

Regarding the memory usage on GPU, you can always set the memory growth at the start of your code like mentioned [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu#limiting_gpu_memory_growth).